# What is the purpose of using Interface in repository pattern?

Tags: .net-core

I dont understand why need extra code/work to use interface?

With Interface,

View <-> BL Interface <-> BL <-> Repository Interface <-> Repository

Without Interface,

View <-> BL <-> Repository

Without interface has less work to do.

You still have to use interface? And why?

Comment: It's to decouple implementation from dependencies. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/244476/44101 for instance.

Comment: in ASP.NET Core, it works great for dependency injection.